# Server Redirecting To First Website

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have been unsuccessfully trying to set up Ubuntu Desktop 32bit in Virtualbox as a name based virtual host. The ip address of the virtual host is 192.168.0.105.

The document roots are `/var/www/example1.com/public_html/index.html` and `/var/www/example2.com/public_html/index.html`

Configurations files are `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com.conf` and 
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example2.com.conf`

**Contents of `example1.com.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Contents of `example2.com.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example2.com
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Contents of `/etc/hosts`**

```
192.168.0.105 example1.com
192.168.0.105 example2.com
```

I have disabled the default config files using `a2dissite` and enabled `example1.com.conf` and `example2.com.conf` using `a2ensite` and then reloaded apache2.

Whenever I type example2.com or example1.com the browser is not taking me to the configured website but when I type the servers IP address it works but only directs to example1.com. Any help in this regard will be deeply respected and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good. I guess you didn't issue `a2ensite`:

The directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` just holds (a collection of) *available* sites. To actually *enable* them, you need to run

```
a2ensite example1.com.conf
a2ensite example2.com.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```

The first two commands do nothing more than creating symlinks in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory that point to the respective files in the `sites-available` directory:

```
root@myhost:/etc/apache2# ll sites-enabled/
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Mär  9 19:06 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Mär 18 16:48 example1.com.conf -> ../sites-available/example1.com.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Mär 18 16:48 example2.com.conf -> ../sites-available/example2.com.conf
```

Apache reads the files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and ignores `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. The general idea is:

1. put all your virtual host configuration files in `sites-available`
2. turn them on or off using `a2ensite $config_file` or `a2dissite $config_file`.

Note that autocompletion usually works, i.e. `a2ensite ex`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> lists the available configurations starting with `ex`.

After `a2ensite` or `a2dissite` you need to make apache aware of this by issuing `systemctl reload apache2`. The commands will tell you something to that effect.

Comment: Thank you for replying.I have actually done that already forgot to mention it in question.I have edited the last portion of my question a bit.